# How to run a process in the background in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a normal flex app that allows you to enter a code. When you enter this code, it pops the code into a queue. I the have a process in the background that hits this queue and takes each code, sends it to a webservice and then responds with a result. Based on the result, the screen is then also updated. The problem is, I want the user to be able to keep entering codes without having the annoying clock show up stopping him from doing anything until the process is done.

So...

1. Is there a way to run a background process on Flex?
2. How do you do it, what's it called?

Answer (score 0):

Close the native window but let the Application run in the background

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.autoExit = false;
NativeWindow(this.stage.nativeWindow).close();
```